# What is the difference between pthread_self() and gettid()? Which one should I use?

Tags: linux, pthreads, affinity

I'm trying to set the CPU affinity of threads on Linux.  I'd like to know which one of the following approaches is recommended:

1. > Get thread id using pthread_self()
   >
   > Set CPU affinity using pthread_setaffinity_np(....) by passing the thread id as an argument
2. > Get thread id using the gettid() call
   >
   > Set CPU affinity using sched_setaffinity(....) by passing the thread id in the place of the process id

P.S: After setting the CPU affinity, I intend to increase the scheduling priority of the thread.

Comment: roelf - I landed on this question because I have a similar question. I noticed you did not accept cnicutar's answer. Can you point out what us wrong with it? (I'm trying to avoid an incorrect assumption).

Answer (score 24):

**They are not the same**. Here are some bits I collected from **[TLPI](http://man7.org/tlpi/)** (I couldn't find a large-enough block that completely describes this). If you're in a hurry you probably want just the last part.

#### `gettid`

Linux 2.4 introduced a new system call, `gettid()`, to allow a thread to obtain its own thread ID.

Each thread within a thread group is distinguished by a unique thread identifier. A thread ID is represented using the same data type that is used for a process ID, `pid_t`. Thread IDs are unique system-wide, and the kernel guarantees that no thread ID will be the same as any process ID on the system, except when a thread is the thread group leader for a process.

#### `pthread_self`

Each thread within a process is uniquely identified by a thread ID. A thread can obtain its own ID using `pthread_self()`.

The `pthread_equal()` function is needed to compare thread ids because the `pthread_t` data type must be treated as **opaque data**.

In the Linux threading implementations,  thread IDs are unique across processes. However, this is not necessarily the case on other implementations, and **SUSv3 explicitly notes that an application can’t  portably use a thread ID to identify a thread in another process**.

#### `gettid` vs `pthread_self`

POSIX thread IDs are not the same as the thread IDs returned by the Linux-specific `gettid()` system call. POSIX thread IDs are assigned and maintained by the threading implementation. The thread ID returned by `gettid()` is a number (similar to a process ID) that is assigned by the kernel.

I would go with `pthread_setaffinity_np` but be aware that the manual says:

> These functions are implemented on top
>   of the sched_setaffinity(2)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fact that `gettid()` exists only as a system call and hasn't been exposed directly as an API call could mean "use it only if you're absolutely certain of what you're doing" and `gettid()` is not meant to be portable.

You should be better if you stick to `pthread`. You can change scheduling policy/priority later with `pthread_setschedparam()`

Comment: Library support was added in glibc 2.30.