# Does Posix thread ID have an one-to-one relation with linux thread ID?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, linuxthreads

I know the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372102/) between `pthread_self()` and `syscall(SYS_gettid)`. `pthread_create()` produces a POSIX thread ID which is represented by a struct pthread_t which is usually defined as an `unsigned long int`. We can use `pthread_self` to get the [ID of the thread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) generated by `pthread_create`.

With `strace`, I know that `pthread_create()` in libpthread.so.0 is implemented by calling `clone` system call, which is also the system call used for `fork()`. After creating a POSIX thread by calling `pthread_create()`, a new POSXI thread (identified by thread ID returned by `pthread_self()`) and a new linux thread(identified by thread ID returned by `syscall(SYS_gettid)`) are produced. Does this mean POSIX thread ID have an one-to-one relation with linux thread ID? They just respectively represent the thread with `pthread_t` and `pid_t`?

Actually, sometimes I found that one linux thread ID maps to several POSIX thread IDs in the same process, which means that after producing a pair of POSIX thread ID and linux thread ID by calling `pthread_create()`, the POSIX thread ID changes while linux thread ID stays the same. Is there any way to change the POSIX thread ID while keeping the linux thread ID unchanged? If there is, which `pthread` function is it?

Thank you.

Here is the log by intercepting `fork` and `pthread_create` call. `ltid` means linux thread ID, `tid` means POSIX thread ID, `pid` means process ID.

```
1 message:  fork pid:12832  ltid:12832  tid:140300035462976     child pid:12848 ltid:12848  tid:140300035462976

2 message:  fork pid:12848  ltid:12848  tid:140549640255296     child pid:12849 ltid:12849  tid:140549640255296

3 message:  fork pid:12848  ltid:12848  tid:140549640255296     child pid:12850 ltid:12850  tid:140549640255296

4 message:  fork pid:12848  ltid:12848  tid:140549640255296     child pid:12851 ltid:12851  tid:140549640255296

5 message:  pthread_create pid:12848    ltid:12848  tid:139968995022656     child ltid:12865    tid:139968995018496 

6 message:  pthread_create pid:12848    ltid:12865  tid:139968995018496     child ltid:12865    tid:139968933345024

7 message:  fork pid:12832  ltid:12832  tid:140300035462976     child pid:12885 ltid:12885  tid:140300035462976

8 message:  fork pid:12885  ltid:12885  tid:139870512949056     child pid:12886 ltid:12886  tid:139870512949056
```

My explanation:

1. (pid=12832, ltid=12832, tid=140...976) calls `fork` producing (pid=12848, ltid=12848, tid=140...976)
2. (pid=12848, ltid=12848, tid=140...296) calls `fork` producing (pid=12849, ltid=12849, tid=140...296)
3. (pid=12848, ltid=12848, tid=139...656) calls `pthread_create` producing (ltid=12865, tid=139...496)

The caller of `2` is the result of `1` according to linux thread ID(12848), but they have different POSIX thread IDs. The same goes for `1` and `5`.

Here is the interception code fragment.

```
void *intermedia(void * arg){

    struct thread_param *temp;

    void *(*start_routine) (void *);
    temp=(struct thread_param *)arg;

    char test[1024]="";
    sprintf(test,"child ltid:%ld\ttid:%lu\n",syscall(SYS_gettid),pthread_self());
    log_message(test)

    return temp->start_routine(temp->args);    
}


int  pthread_create(pthread_t  *thread,  const pthread_attr_t  *attr,  void  *(*start_routine)(void  *),  void  *arg){
    static void *handle = NULL;
    static P_CREATE old_create=NULL;
    if( !handle )
    {
        handle = dlopen("libpthread.so.0", RTLD_LAZY);
        old_create = (P_CREATE)dlsym(handle, "pthread_create");
    }
    pthread_t tmp=pthread_self();
    char test[1024]="";
    sprintf(test,"pthread_create pid:%d\tptid:%ld\ttid:%lu\n",getpid(),syscall(SYS_gettid),tmp);
    log_message(test);

    struct thread_param *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct thread_param));
    temp->args=arg;
    temp->start_routine=start_routine;

    int result=old_create(thread,attr,intermedia,(void *)temp);

    return result;
}

pid_t fork(void){
    static void *handle = NULL;
    static FORK old_fork=NULL;
    if( !handle )
    {
        handle = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
        old_fork = (FORK)dlsym(handle, "fork");
    }

    char test[1024]="";
    sprintf(test,"fork pid:%d\tltid:%ld\ttid:%lu\t",getpid(),syscall(SYS_gettid),pthread_self());

    pid_t ppid=getpid();
    pthread_t ptid=pthread_self();
    pid_t result=old_fork();
    if(result==0){
        sprintf(test,"%s\tchild pid:%d\tltid:%ld\ttid:%lu\n",test,getpid(),syscall(SYS_gettid),pthread_self());
        log_message(test);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The tag "linuxthreads" seems to be wrong in the context, as "linuxthreads" are different from POSIX threads.

Comment: @alk Does it means linux kernel thread? If it's not proper, I can delete this tag.

Comment: On the history on threading on Linux: http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/nptl-the-new-implementation-of-threads-f/184406204 (reading might bring clarity on the different wordings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Posix thread ID have an one-to-one relation with linux thread ID

Yes.

But consider this an implementation detail. Other OSs might do this differently.

---

> which is usually defined as

`pthread_t` is opaque. As well do not make any assumptions on how it is implemented.

---

> I found that one linux thread ID maps to several POSIX thread IDs

Really? I doubt this. At least not if all POSIX thread Ids in question were valid, that is the related thread either had not been joined yet or, if running detached, the thread had not ended yet.

Comment: They are all valid in my test case. Because I intercepted all `pthread_create()` call to record the parent-child relation between threads.

Comment: They are all valid in my test case. Because I intercepted all `pthread_create()` call to record the parent-child relation between threads. I found the threads with the same linux thread ID but different POSIX thread ID all called `pthread_create()`, which means they were executed.

Comment: sorry to post almost the same comment again. It is a mistake. I will post the recorded log and corresponding code fragments soon. Thank you.

Comment: It seems the `pthread_t` is basically a storage address. So if your program happens to have the same storage address available, it seems different pthreads actually seem to have the same value of `pthread_t`, like 139784211150592 in a 64-bit system.